# PayPal Account Balance -0 USD

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I need some help about paypal sandbox accounts. I try to add some money to my account but I'm not able to do that. I create a 6 buyer accounts and I try to add 100 USD for testing and every time account is created but there is no money.

Any help ?

Answer (score 1):

How are you trying to add the funds to your account.  If you have not tried logging into the actual test sandbox seller or buyer account, try logging into the account.  Then going to add funds from the bank account.  Once you initiate the transfer, then go into the details of that transaction and clear the pending transfer.  This should allow you to add funds to your account this way.

Comment: I can't describe how I'm feel now, thanks man.Thanks a lot..In my final exam this post will be a reference.You save my time. Regards !

Comment: That does not seem to work anymore. The bank account transfer option is turned off in my case. It looks like the account is setup to take money from a credit card, but that's not an option from the Add Money menu. Not only that, it is asking me for some social security number... why make it that complicated on a test account?