# PayPal Sandbox - Multiple Issues

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

[rant] I've about had it with the new PayPal dev environment.  While it looks cool, there are several serious issues that makes it an embarrassing release for PayPal [/rant]

## Main Issue: Test funds 0 USD, no matter what I do

I've tried the following:

- Deleting personal test account and recreating
- Adding funding from "bank account" (but I have to confirm my identity with an SSN/TaxID, which I fictitiously do not know)
- Adding a fake credit card (4111111111111111 is already in use; fictitious card numbers are actually validated, and won't work)

## Other issues / complaints:

**Shouldn't have to login to a real PayPal account to QA a checkout workflow**

My client could create her own test account and use that, but then I'd have to change the business email address for the checkout workflow.  We can't test concurrently without one of us having access to the other's real PayPal account.  This change was a good idea in theory, but the implementation isn't there yet.

**Serious cookie issues**

It's bad enough that the "Logout" function (https://developer.paypal.com/cgi-bin/devscr?cmd=_logout) gives a 503 error.  We literally have to clear cookies constantly just to rule out that whatever bug isn't caused by cookies.

**Can't login to sandbox site from developer test accounts page**

There's a nice little helper link that says "Sandbox Site" under each test account.  One would think that clicking on it would log you into the sandbox with that account.  Nope.

## WTF, PayPal

I've had various issues (other than the ones listed here) since the new developer site was launched early this month.  Not once have I seen a formal recognition of issues from PayPal.  A little status message of "Hey, we're working on it!" would give me what I need to explain my delays to clients.

I absolutely love the new interface.  I would love it even more if it worked.

Comment: Is there a question in this? This seems like a bug report / feature request for PayPal, and I'm not sure there's anything we can do about this.

Comment: Fair point. Paypal directs people to SO for these issues.  I was hoping for validation / workarounds.

Comment: For bugs and feature requests, I'd still go direct to PayPal support. Your primary question looks like it might be addressed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15487576/paypal-account-balance-0-usd , but if if isn't, could you rewrite the above to focus on one issue and your question about that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Main Issue: Test funds 0 USD, no matter what I do**

We are currently working on a fix to address this issue. I will have additional details to share regarding this issue later today. I will be sure to update my answer as soon as I have an update. At this point, you will experience intermittent success when creating new accounts. As a workaround, you can log into one of your test accounts and add funds from a bank account manually. Once you initiate the transfer, go into the details of that transaction and clear the pending transfer. This should allow you to add funds to your account.

Update: This issue should now be resolved.

**Shouldn't have to login to a real PayPal account to QA a checkout workflow**

We understand that it is frustrating to have to log in using PayPal access using a live PayPal account. This does however eliminate the need to have to maintain two separate accounts for PayPal.com and developer.paypal.com. I will make sure to share this feedback with our Sandbox team.

**Serious cookie issues**

We are working to address the log in issues that are causing these errors. I will make sure to update this question as soon as I have additional details on the fix for this issue. As you mentioned the workaround is to clear cache and cookies or try another web browser.

Update: This issue should also be resolved. Please let me know if you experience any issues while logging in.

**Can't login to sandbox site from developer test accounts page**

This is great feedback. I will share this with our Sandbox team to see if we can possibly address this problem in a future release.

**Error when clicking on the Profile page in Sandbox**

This was a known issue and a fix was done last night to address this problem. You should no longer receive errors when attempting to access the profile page in a sandbox account.

Thanks,

Comment: Jared... you are the man.  Thanks for taking my harsh criticism like a champ.  I just had no way of knowing what issues were known, what has workarounds, etc.  Maybe we could get a comprehensive overview of known issues posted somewhere.  Thanks so much!

Comment: No problem at all. I am glad to help :). I will update you about the above issues soon. Thanks for your patience!

Comment: Just to clarify with the single-signon--why is it necessary to login to the developer account before being able to use a test account in the checkout process?  Also--with adding funds via a bank account, it's asking me for an SSN/TaxID #, but I never entered one on the account.  How can I verify the backup funding source in sandbox?

Comment: Can you please send your sandbox email address to the email listed in my profile?

Comment: Without signing in into dev portal, we'll still have the _limitation from using one cc number for multiple email addresses_. I wrote my short note here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26049599/420203