# Paypal Sandbox: Using cc number for multiple email addresses

Tags: selenium, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to use selenium for my smoke test. When I test it manually from my desktop, it works just fine. But it always failed in the automated test with the error of: unabel to use cc because it's already registered with other email address or something like that.

How to get away from this inconsistent behaviour?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Paypal already lifted the requirement of logging in into developer site in order to use sandbox site (https://stackoverflow.com/a/15508134/420203). However it will always trigger a "create new user" scenario. The error message will be something around: you cannot use the cc number linked to another email (probably from the billing info).

To remove this limitation, always sign in into dev portal before using sandbox site.